# Is it possible to connect with Hainan Airlines from India/Bangladesh?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, tickets, airlines

I am looking into the option of visiting Mexico with a direct flight of Hainan Airlines from PEK, Beijing. But I cannot find any flight option to fly from India or Bangladesh that would connect with the Hainan flight, enabling me to have a single itinerary and PNR, allowing me to use the 24-hour Chinese transit without visa.

I have a Bangladeshi passport, with only Indian and Mexican visas on it. Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you constrained to that particular flight? Can't you use a site like SkyScanner or Kayak to find other itineraries?

Comment: Mainly because this seems to be the only way to allow me a visa free travel. The cheapest routes require US/Canada visa, which is very hectic and time consuming even for a transit, and the Lufthansa flights need a Schengen transit, for which I would also need a visa.

Answer (score 3):

Singapore allows a [visa-free transit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Singapore#Visa-free_transit) for nationals of Bangladesh (which is an [Assessment Level II country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Singapore#Assessment_Level_II_Countries) in Singapore's classification). Singapore Airlines offers direct flights from Dhaka to Singapore and Singapore to Beijing.

Comment: The issue I am having is, I need the tickets on a single itinerary, otherwise I don't think I would be able to board the plane due to absence of chinese visa, because seperate rickets would mean that for the first part my final destination is China.

Comment: @Aftab: As far as I can tell, the tickets don't have to be on the same itinerary, the requirement is you must buy the onward ticket before entering China.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a single PNR to be able to use the 24 TWOV facility. All you need is to have tickets for flights that arrive and leave within 24 hours. Plenty of direct flights DEL/BOM<->PEK.